# Google Analytics shows Direct User Interaction to Internal Pages

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a website which contains 3 webpages(1 Landing and 2 Internal pages)

For example, www.exmaple.com is my website and the User should log in here and then only he/she redirects to  www.example.com/page1 and he can finish some info and he can go to www.example.com/page2.
I have created google analytics for my website (www.example.com) and added analytics code to all 3 pages(page1 and page2). But User flow of google analytics shows some of the users are directly accessing to page1 and page 2

But I am sure all users will come to landing page first (www.example.com), Can anyone help me how they can access page1 and page 2 directly (I am sure it is not because of bookmarks)

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses redirects, the redirecting page becomes the landing page's referrer. Depending on how you do the redirect you can lose the referrer.

So if your original referrer is www.google.com, your Google Analytics code is not loaded in this page and after redirect the new referrer becomes www.example.com, therefore on the actual landing the referral is itself (www.example.com) and no longer www.google.com and the source of session is Direct.